# can not run play framework activator

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I am unable to run activator, its like the activator couldn't download some dependencies. It happened with both min and offline distribution. 
Here console error:

```
[22-Feb-2015 09:41:52] /Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app 
$> /Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/activator run
[info] Loading project definition from /Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/project
[info] Updating {file:/Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/project/}fist-app-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to fist-app (in build file:/Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/)
[info] Updating {file:/Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] javax.transaction#jta;1.1!jta.javadoc.zip:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/djnainggolan/.ivy2/local/javax.transaction/jta/1.1/javadoc.zips/jta.javadoc.zip
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   file:/Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/repository/javax.transaction/jta/1.1/javadoc.zips/jta.javadoc.zip
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.javadoc.zip
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.javadoc.zip
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/javax.transaction/jta/1.1/javadoc.zips/jta.javadoc.zip
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.javadoc.zip
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3!hamcrest-core.src.zip:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/djnainggolan/.ivy2/local/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/src.zips/hamcrest-core.src.zip
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   file:/Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app/repository/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/src.zips/hamcrest-core.src.zip
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.src.zip
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.src.zip
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/src.zips/hamcrest-core.src.zip
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.src.zip
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: javax.transaction#jta;1.1!jta.javadoc.zip
[warn]  :: org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3!hamcrest-core.src.zip
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.transaction#jta;1.1!jta.javadoc.zip
download failed: org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3!hamcrest-core.src.zip
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.transaction#jta;1.1!jta.javadoc.zip
[error] download failed: org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3!hamcrest-core.src.zip
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Feb 22, 2015 9:42:55 AM
[22-Feb-2015 09:42:55] /Volumes/oc/workspace/fist-app 
$>
```

Please help.
THanks

Comment: Show us the section `libraryDependencies` of your `build.sbt` file. Not sure, but it seems like you're trying to get javadoc and sources whereas they're not available...

Comment: I found the solution by remove ~/.ivy and ~/sbt forlders, I think the ivy folder was conflict with ivy with my another program.
 But why create new/run activator from offline distribution still donwload all of those dependencies, is tat normal?